# My google maps reloads(and re-centres) when I turn layers back on

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm building a google map for a community project and I'm having troubles figuring out why my map re-centres (and obviously reloads) every time I turn a layer back on. Any insight on why this may be happening is very much appreciated.

See map here: http://www.northerntechnomics.com/lmantzel/googlemap/maptest12.html

If you open up the side bar and uncheck a layer then move the map around and check the layer again you will see what I mean.

How I display layers:

HTML (checking or unchecking triggers check() function)

```
     <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><label><input type="checkbox" id="Trail" checked="checked" onclick="check()" />Hub Trail</label></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><label><input type="checkbox" id="Markers" checked="checked" onclick="check()" />Markers</label></a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><label><input type="checkbox" id="Slider" checked="checked" onclick="check()" />Image Slider</label></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript

```
    function check() 
        {
            if(document.getElementById('Trail').checked)
              {TrailLayer.setMap(map);}
            else 
              {TrailLayer.setMap(null);}    

            if(document.getElementById('Markers').checked)
            {
                MarkerVisibility = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++)
                {
                    gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                MarkerVisibility = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++)
                {
                    gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
                }
                if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
            }
            if(document.getElementById('Slider').checked)
            {
                document.getElementById('imageSlider').style.display = 'block';
            }

            else 
            {
                 document.getElementById('imageSlider').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
```

Unchecking and checking any layer causes the map to reload either on the check or the uncheck. There is no code that re-initiates the map. I know others have been able to do layers without having these issues please help me before I have to recode it all!

*Full code can be seen by viewing source of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'layers" are [google.maps.KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) objects.

```
var TrailLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                    url: 'http://www.northerntechnomics.com/lmantzel/googlemap/Trail5.kml'

                  });
```

Use the [preserveViewport:true option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions) if you don't want them to automatically zoom and center to show the content.